# tree maps in JUNG (for a shortest path algorithm)

Tags: java, path-finding, shortest-path, graph-algorithm, jung

After asking some general advice on shortest path algorithms ([2D waypoint pathfinding: combinations of WPs to go from curLocation to targetLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194482/2d-waypoint-pathfinding-combinations-of-wps-to-go-from-curlocation-to-targetloca)) and then asking about a more specific implementation ([Shortest path algorithm (eg. Dijkstra's) for 500+ waypoints/nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234557/shortest-path-algorithm-eg-dijkstras-for-500-waypoints-nodes/5234830#5234830)) I have decided to use the JUNG library (http://jung.sf.net/).

**My goal is now to get the shortest path from point A to point B by using any combination of points from a list of points (size ~1000) where each point is directly connected to all points that are within x distance.**

For this, I need to setup  a tree map. I believe that this is a list of tree map implementations: http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/class-use/Hypergraph.html#edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.shortestpath

Is that correct? Now, all these implementations limit themselves to sparse tree maps, yet I have to create a rather dense tree map.

So, what tree map should I use in JUNG to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main goal is achievable with JUNG but IMHO, you need to filter for your given "x" distance (I mean all possible node-to-node combinations). However, I have no experience in using JUNG's shortest path algorithms except in the example it gives below.

JUNG Framework 2.x GUI example uses a shortest-path algorithm from **BFSDistanceLabeler** that requires a generic **Hypergraph**. It applies a BFS distance-based calculation rather than edge weight-based distance calculation. It is a Breadth-first search (BFS) algorithm, though.

You can refer to the source code **ShortestPathDemo.class** under **package edu.uci.ics.jung.samples** in **jung-samples-2.0.1.jar**

The best reference I can find for other JUNG's shortest path algorithms can be found here (PDF):
[www.grotto-networking.com/JUNG/JUNG2-Tutorial.pdf](http://www.grotto-networking.com/JUNG/JUNG2-Tutorial.pdf)

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something but how does this answer what JUNG tree map implementation is applicable for dense rather than sparse tree maps?

Comment: A list of point about 1000 nodes is not an issue in JUNG as long as the hardware and the JVM are capable to handle the size. I do notice this constraint in my JUNG implementations. Why a tree when you can use a graph considering that your intention is for 2-D waypoint data? You can specify your own data types in JUNG generic Graph, Hyper-graph or Tree class. Though, it has a limited support for trees ((directed, rooted) tree) which I haven't tried. See JUNG FAQ if you haven't: http://jung.sourceforge.net/faq.html

Comment: I thought a graph is a tree. But you're right it's a 2D environment. I looked at this sample before, but it really doesn't make much sense to me. For example, where do they actually construct and populate the graph? If you could give a small example in code here for a non-gui shortest path implementation in jung that'd be great.